# Reactjs: glue React code together old javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a Message component which displays some text, inside its **text/babel** script. Then I have my old javascript code inside its script (**javascript**).

What's the best practice to update the value of the text of the Message component from the "old javascript" code?

```
<script src="js/libs/react.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">

class Message extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {text: "Default text"};
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <p>{this.state.text}</p>
        )
    }
  }; // class

ReactDOM.render(
     <Message />,
    document.getElementById('reactRoot')

</script>
```

now the javascript code

```
<script>
// think here we are for example inside async code 
// how should I update the text of Message from here?
message.update("new text") // ??? 
</script>
```

**how I do refer to the message component created**?

Answer (score 0):

You can employ a dirty trick like this:

```
class Message extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {text: "Default text"};
      window.setMessageText = function(txt){
      this.setState({text:txt})
      }.bind(this)
    }
```

and use it like `window.setMessageText("newMessage")`

, or you can setup an event system (which I would recommend as a good practice), subscribe to your event in the component constructor and publish events in the old/legacy code

Here's a handy library: https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter

Comment: I'd like not to pollute the global scope; talking about the event solution I thought it but I was wondering how to access the inverse way (what I see as the "direct" one)

Comment: I believe it would be direct, if I get you right. You would say eventBus.emit('NEW_MESSAGE', 'Message here') in the old code. You may even use jQuery custom events to avoid globals other than jQuery

Comment: ...or even keep a registry (once again, global) of the created components and referring to those directly with registry['message'].setState(....)